# In Perl, how can I read a file and save entire content of file in %hash in the form of key and values?

Tags: perl, hash, readfile, key-value

Hi i am new to Perl programming. I am trying to read a `.csv` file which has 2 fields separated by comma.

I want to put all the data of a file into a hash in the form of key and its value.

The input file I have is

#### Data

```
2.8, gitu

2.5,  Has


2.7  Hwait

3.1-weiity

4.2,  city

2.7:query

4.9,  city

16.2,  play

6.2,  game

7,,,8 Jami

4.0,  city
```

This line of code does not print all the valid data present in the input file. Valid data is in the form of
a line start with a number have a comma in between and then a name. Else invalid entries should be ignored. It skips few valid entries to display when I print `%hashforHighMagnitude;`
Please tell me where I am missing ? How can I get all the valid entries present `%hashforHighMagnitude;`

I am trying to do this

```
open ( OF, "$inputFile") or die "Cant open input file: $!\n";
while ( $Line =<OF>) {

    if($Line =~ /^\d+\.+\d*\s*,\s*\w+$/g)              
    {
        ( my $magnitude, my $place ) = split(/,/,$Line);

        $hashforHighMagnitude{$place} = $magnitude;
        $hash{$place}++;
    }
    else
    {
        next;
    }
}

print %hashforHighMagnitude;

close(OF);
```

output should be

```
2.8, gitu

2.5,  Has

4.2,  city

4.9,  city

16.2,  play

6.2,  game

4.0,  city
```

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015061/csv-into-hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i was able to find my mistake . what i was doing wrong was that i was not able to add all the entries properly. i was needed to replace my line of code from

```
$hashforHighMagnitude{$place} = $magnitude;
```

to

```
$hashforHighMagnitude{$place} .=exists $hashforHighMagnitude{$place} ? "  $magnitude" :$magnitude;
```

thats it. 
now i was able to get the desired output ... 
thanks everyone for taking a look at my query .....

Answer (score 6):

Due to the presence of edge cases while parsing CSVs, a specialised module should be used. Some modules worth considering are:

- [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV)
- [`Text::CSV_PP`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV_PP)
- [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS)

### Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { 'allow_whitespace' => 1 } )
  or die Text::CSV->error_diag;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
    if ( @$row == 2 ) {
        print join( ', ', @$row ), "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
2.8, gitu
2.5,  Has
2.7  Hwait
3.1-weiity
4.2,  city
2.7:query
4.9,  city
16.2,  play
6.2,  game
7,,,8 Jami
4.0,  city
```

### Output

```
2.8, gitu
2.5, Has
4.2, city
4.9, city
16.2, play
6.2, game
4.0, city
```