# Perl parse csv file and iterate curl

Tags: csv, perl, parsing, curl

I am trying to parse a csv file and iterate through it with curl. The following is my data set:

> ```
> Act No. 2,Sep/1900/28
> Act No. 3,Sep/1900/28
> Act No. 10,Oct/1900/28
> ```

I have followed this Stackoverflow question: [CSV into hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015061/csv-into-hash) to basically create hash for my data set.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;
use IO::File;

use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $url = "https://elibrary.judiciary.gov.ph/thebookshelf/docmonth/";
#my $filestoprocess = 'list_acts.csv';

# Usage example:
my $hash_ref = csv_file_hashref('toharvest_og_sourcing.csv');

foreach my $key (sort keys %{$hash_ref}){

my $urlcomplete = "$url"."@{$hash_ref->{$key}}";
   
#start the curl
my $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140319 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.4.0";

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
#$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
#$curl->curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $urlcomplete);

# A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

# Starts the actual request
my $retcode = $curl->perform;

# Looking at the results...
    if ($retcode == 0) {
        my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  my $curledurldate = $response_body;
  our ($issuancelink) = $curledurldate =~ /a href='(https.*?)'>.*?<STRONG>$key/s;
  #print "$issuancelink\n";

        if (defined $issuancelink) {

my $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140319 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.4.0";

#my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
#$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
#$curl->curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $issuancelink);

# A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

# Starts the actual request
my $retcode = $curl->perform;

# Looking at the results...
if ($retcode == 0) {
#       print("Transfer went ok\n");
        my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      my $curledsource = $response_body;
      our ($ogsourcing) = $curledsource =~ /<br>\s+(\w+.*?)\s+?<CENTER>.*?H2/s;
    
        my $filename = 'ogsourcingharvested.txt';
              open (FH, '>>', $filename) or die("Could not open file. $!");
                #print "Error processing ".$fh."$_\n";
                                print FH $ogsourcing."|"."{$key}\n";
               close (FH);       
        }

        else {
        # Error code, type of error, error message
        print("An error happened: $retcode ".$curl->strerror($retcode)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n");

        }
} else {
        # Error code, type of error, error message
        print("An error happened: $retcode ".$curl->strerror($retcode)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n");
}

}
}

# Implementation:
sub csv_file_hashref {
   my ($filename) = @_;

   my $csv_fh = IO::File->new($filename, 'r');
   my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ();

   my %output_hash;

   while(my $colref = $csv->getline ($csv_fh))
   {
      $output_hash{shift @{$colref}} = $colref;
   }

   return \%output_hash;
}
```

Basically, the code iterates through the second column, add that to the end of a URL, then that URL is curled. Afterwards, the content of the curled URL is searched for a particular content:

```
our ($issuancelink) = $curledurldate =~ /a href='(https.*?)'>.*?<STRONG>$key/s;
```

When that link shows up in search, that is put into a variable ($issuancelink) and then that variable $issuancelink is curled. Then a particular text in the curled file is searched, after which that particular text is captured and saved to a text file. However, my code is good if the second column (Sep/1900/28, Oct/1900/28 in this case) aren't repeated. However, if it's repeated, that is where I am having a problem, it seems the first iteration is the one being captured. So in my case, the link for Act No. 3 which has same originating URL (https://elibrary.judiciary.gov.ph/thebookshelf/docmonth/Sep/1900/28) as Act No. 2 (https://elibrary.judiciary.gov.ph/thebookshelf/docmonth/Sep/1900/28), the link for Act No. 2 is instead the one captured.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a lot of code. Please [edit] your question and format it properly, it is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

> However, my code is good if the second column (Sep/1900/28, Oct/1900/28 in this case) aren't repeated.

When you store values in a hash, the hash keys are unique. That means that if you have identical key names, they will overwrite each other.

This part of your code:

```
   while(my $colref = $csv->getline ($csv_fh))
   {
      $output_hash{shift @{$colref}} = $colref;
   }
```

Seems to be responsible. What you can do is to save the values in an array instead of a scalar (in this case, in an array ref).

I would do something like this:

```
   while(my $colref = $csv->getline ($csv_fh))
   {
      my ($key, $value) = @$colref;
      push @{$output_hash{$key}}, $value;       # store values in array
   }
```

Another benefit of this is that the values are copied. In your code, the array ref is copied. You are saved from problems by the limited scope of your variable `my $colref`, but generally speaking copying the values will save you from problems.

To access the array values you will probably need to loop for each hash key. Something like

```
for my $key (sort keys %$hash_ref) {
    for my $values (@{$hash_ref{$key}}) {
          # do stuff...
```

Comment: Hi TLP! Thanks for the answer. I'm trying your code for, I'm getting this error: Global symbol "%hash_ref" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %hash_ref"?) at test2.pl line 17. I don't know what to replace for %hash_ref.

Comment: @schnydszch Well, that is very simple. You tried to use a hash variable that you did not declare. Probably you declared `my $hash_ref`, and you tried to use `$hash_ref{foo}`. The latter refers to a hash value in the hash `%hash_ref`. What you need to do is to use `$hash_ref->{foo}` which is the proper way to access a hash ref.